# Using os.listdir(), see if an object is a file or a directory

Tags: python-2.7, filesystems

Here is the code i wrote:

```
import os

    for item in os.listdir("C:/"):
        if os.path.isfile(item):
            print(item + " is a file")
        elif os.path.isdir(item):
            print(item + " is a dir")
        else:
            print("Unknown!")
```

Response:

```
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!
Unknown!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What i did wrong.
I think maybe it is because the folder is locked or encrypted.
Please give a hand!

Thanks a lot

Comment: `print(item + " is neither file nor dir")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the complete path to `isfile()` and `isdir()`.

```
import os


path = "C:"
for item in os.listdir(path):
    item = os.path.join(path, item)
    if os.path.isfile(item):
        print(item + " is a file")
    elif os.path.isdir(item):
        print(item + " is a dir")
    else:
        print("Unknown!")
```

Comment: But the path needs to be like this:
path = "C:/"